# Microsoft Ajax Minifier output path access error when called from Python

Tags: python, microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

I'm calling Microsoft Ajax Minifier from Python like so:

```
minifyArguments = ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\AjaxMin.exe"]

for f in filesToMinify:
    minifyArguments.append(f)

minifyArguments.append("–out")
minifyArguments.append("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\TestFolder") #minifyJSDestinationPath
minifyArguments.append("–clobber")

ajaxMinProcess = subprocess.Popen(minifyArguments, shell=False)

stdout, stderr = ajaxMinProcess.communicate()
```

This works fine, and I see that it's starting etc. but when it wants to write the output file it gives an error:

AjaxMinifier.exe: error AM-AUTH: Access to the path 'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\TestFolder' is denied.

I have tried different folders, the issue is not exclusive to the one in the code. It can't write to any folder.

When I don't call it from Python but directly from the commandline it works without problems.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

This line:

```
minifyArguments.append("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\TestFolder")
```

Should include the filename, like this:

```
minifyArguments.append("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\script.min.js")
```